# How to take information from a file to python?

Tags: python

I have a file that I can read like this:

```
filein= open('/path/datasets.txt', 'r')
print filein.read()
"V1" "V2" "V3" "V4" "V5" "V6" "V7" "V8" "V9"
"1" "ABCD" "ABCD" "Adam" "29" "591" "25" "54" "25" "NH"
"2" "ABCD" "ABCD" "Alex" "481" "26" "75" "54" "25" "NH"
```

Then use some formation from this file in my code:

```
 Import   …….
 res = data.read(29,591) # res = data.read(V4 [1],V5 [1])
 fileout = open('filename_29_591.txt', 'w') # 'filename_V4 [1]_V5 [1].txt
 fileout.write(res.to_string())
 fileout.close()
```

What I need is to read first line in my filein then take V4 [1], V5 [1] values and use them in the code and then in output.

Do the same for the second line (V4 [2], V5 [2]) and for all lines (make a loop).

```
 res = data.read(481,26) # res = data.read(V4 [2], V5 [2])
 fileout = open('filename_481_26.txt', 'w') # 'filename_V4 [2]_V5 [2].txt
 fileout.write(res.to_string())
 fileout.close()
```

I am pretty new to Python so sorry if the question seems simple to do.

my outputs (saved) are:

```
           filename_29_591.txt
           filename_481_26.txt
```

Comment: What is your desired output here?

Comment: First iteration : Determine which index you will need to look for. Next iterations : Access the indexes you determined earlier, and compute them. Is this explanation simple enough for you ?

Comment: my output is file. I want to distinguish the output files so I put what I used in the file name: `filename_V4_V5.txt`.

Comment: You just need to read specific values from file and assign them to variables. Then you use those variables where you need to reference those values.

Comment: As you updated the question, I get it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
filein = open('/path/datasets.txt', 'r')
lines = filein.readlines()
filein.close()

for line in lines[1:]:
    fields = line.split(' ')
    V4 = int(fields[4].strip('"'))
    V5 = int(fields[5].strip('"'))
    # do something with V4 and V5
    res = data.read(V4, V5)
    fileout = open('filename_{}_{}.txt'.format(V4, V5), 'w')
    fileout.write(res.to_string())
    fileout.close()
```

Comment: @temor Sorry, I forgot to convert them to integer. I just updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Only set correct delimiter:

```
with open('datasets.txt', 'r', encoding = 'UTF-16') as ids:
    reader = csv.reader(ids, delimiter = '\n')
    ids = [x for x in reader]
print(ids[0]) #This is First line
for x in ids:
    print(x[4],x[5]) #These are V5 and V6
```